# How to trigger submit from two buttons using one event in an Angular form?

Tags: angular

I have a form component and two buttons:

```
<ui-form (submit)="..."></ui-form>
<button (click)="save()">save</button>
<button (click)="open()">open</button>
```

When I click the buttons (save or open), I need to submit the form and **only then** continue the function of the button that was clicked.

But I can only have one submit event in `ui-form`.

I want the save button to trigger the submit event and run the save button function. Same for the open function. How should I handle this?

Comment: Cant you just trigger the click event of the ui-form element from your save/open function? very raw example: element.click();

Comment: How about call submit function in `save` and `open` function?

Comment: yes I can trigger the event submit. but it will invoke the submit event of ui-form. how to get back to the button function?

Comment: Pass a function as callback or send some extra parameters and do some logic based on the parameters

Comment: Maybe explain in pseudo code (comments) what you want to create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the attribute to the button and make these buttons part of form to receive the submit events:

```
<ui-form (submit)="onSubmit(buttonType)">
<button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit('save')">save</button>
<button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit('open')">open</button>
</ui-form>
```

In your ts file, you should do this:

```
onSubmit(buttonType): void {
        if(buttonType==="save") {
             // do things here        }
        if(buttonType==="open"){
            // do things here
        }

}
```